# c# image encode performance

Tags: c#, drawing, png

I must draw for the other application some overlay images. I need a resolution of 1920x1080 with transparency. I have tested with `system.drawing` and measured it needs `11ms` only for one png encoding `image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);`

I have also check some other projects [SkiaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp/), [ImageProcessor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageProcessor/), [SharpDX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/) but the performance is worse than `system.drawing`. I have also tested with components of WPF `System.Windows.Media` but is worse too.

I have also found this [blog post 5 Reasons You Should Stop Using System.Drawing from ASP.NET](https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet)

Can someone help me with how I can speed up this logic?

**my code**

```
using (var image = new Bitmap(1920, 1080))
using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    //Some draw logic

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

@sLw i must create for every frame of a video a customize overlay the video has a length of 2 minutes. In this case i need 3000 images for one video. This need 33 seconds only for create the overlays.

@mjwills
Any improvement that is possible takes us forward

@PepitoSh
I have found only this project [pngcs](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngcs) i test this soon

**Update 2**

I have also tested with [`WebP`](https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper) a second format with transparency support. 
But in this format i need `21ms` -> `webp.EncodeLossless(image);`

Comment: I think this is as fast as you can get., unless you find a better png encoder. Maybe you could reuse the bitmap you create only once.

Comment: why is 11 ms bad? on a 60hz it one frame would be 16.6ms, but if you really need it to be faster then we have to wait for a good answer. I think this is interesting

Comment: How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @sLw i have update my question

Comment: @TomBaires so you want to do basic rendering? 33 secs is totaly fine for a 2 minute video.

Comment: can you try parallel?

Comment: @TaW System.Drawing use GDI and have proplems if i parallelize to much

Comment: Do you output your results to the gui or simply store them as files?

Comment: @TaW i hold it in memory and send it direct to an other process

Comment: What has PNG to do with your question? I would guess it is time consuming to continuously compress and decompress, even if "only" in memory. The only time you should worry about "PNG" is if you are reading an external image or writing to one. That requirement does not appear to be there.

Comment: @usr2564301 i forward the bytes of the image as png but hold in memory to an other process

Comment: Hi @TomBaires I am facing similar problem did you solved it somehow?

Comment: @xszaboj sorry, no :(